# Turn array into array of object using map failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const arr = ["a","b","c"]

arr.map(obj => {obj.id: obj})
```

I expect arr can become `[{id:"a"},{id:"b"},{id:"c"}]` but I got error at `obj.id` within my map, what's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use parenthesis for the return object and just the variable `id`, which resolves to an object with the key `id`.

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"],
    result = arr.map(id => ({ id }));

console.log(result);
```

From MDN [Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals):

> #### Returning object literals
>
> Keep in mind that returning object literals using the concise syntax `params => {object:literal}` will not work as expected.
>
> ```
> var func = () => { foo: 1 };               
> // Calling func() returns undefined!
>
> var func = () => { foo: function() {} };   
> // SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
> ```
>
> This is because the code inside braces ({}) is parsed as a sequence of statements (i.e. foo is treated like a label, not a key in an object literal).
>
> Remember to wrap the object literal in parentheses.
>
> ```
> var func = () => ({foo: 1});
> ```

Comment: I see. Do I have to do checking if the arr is empty? `(arr || []).map(id => ({id}))` will this be better?

Comment: @DoeYakrik, what means empty? if no element is in the array, then it is the same as `[]`. but if it is undefined (or falsey), then you need a check, like you have.

Comment: what will happens if I don't do checking? will it breaks? arr is actually user's input.

Comment: i would check any user input. don't trust the user.

Answer (score 0):

you should use extra parenthesis when returning object. so your code will be

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
const a = arr.map((obj, i) => ({
  [i]: obj
}))

console.log(a)
```